# Is there a way to export error messages?

Tags: r, error-handling

My question is quite general and yet it's somehow difficult to produce a reproducible example. When running some long R-script I sometimes get unreasonable errors. Due to the length of the script and the database behind it, it's usually difficult and time consuming to look for the errors. Is there a way to export errors somehow to a text file for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-May/070750.html) an elegant solution :

Define an error function :

```
my.error.fun <- function() {
  cat(geterrmessage(), file="rerr.txt", append=TRUE)
}
```

then,

```
options("error"=my.error.fun)
```